# Does the IBM Xseries 305 Server Support Raid Arrays?

Tags: raid

I'm wondering if the Xseries 305 server supports raid arrays? If so, is there already a chip installed for it?

Comment: Noah - I know you're new here and might not understand how this site works. When people give you accurate answers, you're supposed to mark them with the checkmark to indicate that you've accepted the answer. Read the FAQ if you're unclear. Being rewarded for giving useful answers is how the community here operates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not have a RAID card builtin. It has IDE and SCSI built-in. [It has this for expansion slots:](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/systems/support/system_x_pdf/48p9906.pdf)

> Two 66/100/133 MHz/64-bit PCI-X slots
>   on the system board (one half-length
>   full-height, one low profile)

It will also only fit two slim hard drives, so you can only do RAID 0 or RAID 1 without some form of external storage, like an external SCSI array or a SAN, which would require an HBA card.

Bit of advice : your questions show a lot of "beginner" traits. That's not a bad thing, and I'm not trying to discourage you from asking questions here. However, you might do well to find a qualified or experienced person, either physically near you, or online, that you could engage in a real dialog about what you need for this project. This site is specifically for targeted questions and answers, and I think you would benefit a lot more from an "overview" type of conversation instead.